# Haneke not working with AWS SDK using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, haneke

I am trying to integration with AWS SDK but the image is not showing up.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        let downloadURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent("myImage.jpg")
        let downloadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest()
        downloadRequest.bucket = "stg"
        downloadRequest.key = "myImage.jpg"
        downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL = downloadURL

        let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()
        transferManager.download(downloadRequest).continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in
            if task.error != nil {
                print("Failed to download S3 with error \(task.error)")
            }

            if task.result != nil {
                //let output = task.result as! AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadOutput
                cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
                cell.imageView?.hnk_setImageFromURL(downloadURL)
            }
            return nil
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are updating the UI in the background thread. You should replace `.continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in` with `.continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (task) -> AnyObject! in` to run the block in the main thread.

Also, if you are writing a new app, I recommend using `AWSS3TransferUtility` instead of `AWSS3TransferManager` since we will focus our development effort on the transfer utility and will phase out the support for the transfer manager.

Comment: can you show the full code here based on my question.